# tindercard library not working after one swipe

Tags: java, android, cardview

i have to implement swipe card functionality and after a single swipe, when we move for second swipe it stops working

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".All_Modules.FindMatch.Search">

    <com.tablefortwo.Views.tindercard.SwipeFlingAdapterView
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/trans_grey"
        app:rotation_degrees="15.5" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

this is code for activity

```
public class Search extends BaseActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.frame)
    SwipeFlingAdapterView frame;

    SwipeFlingAdapterView.onFlingListener onFlingListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);


        onFlingListener = new SwipeFlingAdapterView.onFlingListener() {
            @Override
            public void removeFirstObjectInAdapter() {
            }

            @Override
            public void onLeftCardExit(Object dataObject) {
                FlingCardListener.FlingListener flingListener = frame.getFlingListener();
                flingListener.onCardExited();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRightCardExit(Object dataObject) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAdapterAboutToEmpty(int itemsInAdapter) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(float scrollProgressPercent) {

            }
        };

        frame.setFlingListener(onFlingListener);


        SearchAdapter  adapter = new SearchAdapter(mContext);
        frame.setAdapter(adapter);


    }
}
```

this is the code for adapter

```
public class SearchAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context ctx;

   public SearchAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 20;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_item, parent, false);
        }
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

count is static at 20 ...but after first count it stops and doesnot swipe 
further and i need to make it swipe upto the count 20 just like tinder app functionality

Comment: which gradle plugin you're using ?

Comment: Shouldn't you be removing the item as soon as it is swiped and also update the count?

Comment: gradle plugin 3.3.2

Comment: @Rohit5k2 can you share some code that what do you mean

Answer (score 0):

Please remove data from your list as well after swiping the card and then notify your adapter, it will work fine then.